# In matlab, how to write a array of string into a text file and how to read it back?

Tags: arrays, matlab

For example, I have a an array called `namelist` contains the following strings on each column:

```
'img1.png'
'img10.png'
'img100.png'
'img2.png'
...
```

I would like to record this array into a txt file and later read it back. (what I need is the order of those files).

What I am trying now is use

```
dlmwrite('namelist.txt',namelist)
```

But it gives me a really ugly txt file which contains

```
I,m,g,1,.,p,n,g,I,m,g,1,0,.,p,n,g,I,m,g,1,0,0,.,p,n,g,I,m,g,1,0,1,.,p,n,g,I,m,g,2,.,p,n,g,
```

and I have no idea how to read it back, i.e., to have array `nameless` as it before. I tried `dlmread` and `textscan` but none of them works... or I don't know the right way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
%%writting File names
namelist={'img1.png','img10.png','img100.png','img2.png'};
fp=fopen('namelist.txt','w');
for i=1:length(namelist)

    fprintf(fp,'%s\n', namelist{i});


end

fclose(fp);



%%Retriving File names


fileID = fopen('namelist.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s');
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C)
```

Here you go.

Comment: You don't actually need the loop in the write step, remove the loop and  in fprintf replace i with : , i.e. fprintf(fp,'%s\n', namelist{:}); will automatically loop through each element of namelist.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that .